# C# select from Cassandra counter table

Tags: c#, cassandra, counter

I am new to Cassandra counter fields. So I created a test environment.
I can successfully insert into the database, but when I try to select from the database I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Cassandra.dll
>   Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

I got the following database:

```
create table counterInt (
MeterID int, 
DayStamp timestamp,
NumberOfValues counter,
Value1 counter,
PRIMARY KEY ((MeterID), Daystamp));
```

This is my select method:
Edit: the error occurs when it hits `row.GetValue<double>("value1");`
The primary key gets selected.

```
public List<CSVMeter> selectBasic()
{
    Connect();
    var resultList = new List<CSVMeter>();
    RowSet result = session.Execute("select * FROM counterInt");
    foreach (Row row in result.GetRows())
    {
        CSVMeter csvMeter = new CSVMeter();
        csvMeter.MeterID = row.GetValue<int>("meterid");
        csvMeter.PeriodStart = row.GetValue<DateTime>("daystamp");
        csvMeter.Value = row.GetValue<double>("value1");
        csvMeter.NumberOfValues = row.GetValue<double>("numberofvalues");
        resultList.Add(csvMeter);
    }
    CloseConnection();
    return resultList;
}
```

my object:

```
public int MeterID { get; set; }
public DateTime PeriodStart { get; set; }
public double Value { get; set; }
public double Value2 { get; set; }

public CSVMeter(int meterID, DateTime periodStart, double value, double numberOfValues)
{
    this.MeterID = meterID;
    this.PeriodStart = periodStart;
    this.Value = value;
    this.Value2 = value2;
    this.NumberOfValues = numberOfValues;
    this.qualityScore = qualityScore;
}
```

There are values in the `counterInt` table. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JaydipJ I do not understand your question? Its defined in my object as `NumberOfValues`?

Comment: Yes I am asking same since in your object declaration there is no declaration for this field

Comment: @JaydipJ might be an editing error (minimized the code for overview) the problem is not the `numberOfValue` field. The problem occurs when the code reaches `row.GetValue<double>("value1");` Then I get the not recognised exception.

Comment: I am not aware of cassandra just asking for curiosity what kind of data stored in `counter` DataType i.e Int,double,float..

Comment: @JaydipJ Apperiantly i needed to change double to long. Now it does work. Counter is a special row, According to the answer I marked below it are integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

The issue is certainly about the fact that you use `double` type which is a decimal type but the counters are integers and cannot be cast as decimal. You should certainly use `long` instead.

Comment: Correct. Note to other people with this problem: Also insert the data as `long` otherwise you get very very strange values in your database.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/counter_type.html):

> A counter column value is a 64-bit signed integer

You are retrieving it as a `double`. You should use a long instead:

```
csvMeter.Value = row.GetValue<long>("value1");
```